# Django fields editable in create but not in edit

Tags: python, django

I am creating a small application where I am able to add / modify / delete / view a member.

```
def member_edit(request,member_id):

    MemberForm = modelform_factory(Member, fields=('employee_id', 'employee_name'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        member = MemberForm(request.POST)
        if member.is_valid():
            member.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("members:member_view"))
    else:
        member = get_object_or_404(Member, pk=member_id)

    return render(request, 'members/member_edit.html', {'member': member})
```

I notice that instead of being able to edit all the fields become in display mode.

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="{{ member.employee_id.id_for_label }}">Employee id:</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" value = {{ member.employee_id }} /> </td>
        <td> {{ member.employee_id.errors }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="{{ member.employee_name.id_for_label }}">Employee Name:</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" value = {{member.employee_name }} /></td>
        <td> {{ member.employee_name.errors }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
```

If I change the member_edit function to this, it works but I don't have any data to change(obviously) :

```
def member_edit(request,member_id):

    MemberForm = modelform_factory(Member, fields=('employee_id', 'employee_name'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        member = MemberForm(request.POST)
        if member.is_valid():
            member.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("members:member_view"))
    else:
        member = MemberForm() # change made only here

    return render(request, 'members/member_edit.html', {'member': member})
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the member instance to the form.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def member_edit(request, member_id):
    MemberForm = modelform_factory(Member, fields=('employee_id', 'employee_name'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = get_object_or_404(Member, id=member_id)
        member = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if member.is_valid():
            member.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("members:member_view"))
    else:
        member = MemberForm() # change made only here

    return render(request, 'members/member_edit.html', {'member': member})
```

Comment: I made the changes. I now get a TypeError at /members/1/member_edit/ - 'module' object is not callable. `code def member_edit(request,member_id):
     
    post = get_object_or_404(Member, pk=member_id)
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         
        form = MemberForm(request.POST,instance = post)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("members:member_view"),pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = MemberForm(instance=post)`

Comment: Infact, I just noticed that this code fails in create as well now : `member = MemberForm() `. What could be it ?

Comment: I included this in the edit mode and it worked : `MemberForm = modelform_factory(Member, fields=('employee_id', 'employee_name'))`. Can anyone explain ?